# jquery height() returns different values in Chrome and Firefox — on the api.jquery.com demo — why?

Tags: jquery

If I go to

http://api.jquery.com/height/#example-0

and click 'Get Paragraph Height', I get '36px' in Chrome v25 and '34px' in Firefox v19.

I filed a bug (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13538) and the triage nurse suggested it might be something with default stylesheets. (And pointed me to SO.)

Do other people see this behaviour? IS it a bug? If not, can you explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer 10 shows `37px`.

It's to do with how the font is rendered. Every browser renders text slightly differently, be it kerning, pixel-alignment, the position of the baseline, etc..

Our favourite Jeff Atwood has [several](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid.html) blog [posts](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/whats-wrong-with-apples-font-rendering.html) on the subject, explaining font rendering in detail.

Comment: "you'll forgive me if I'm not overly optimistic about this theoretical jump from 100 DPI to 200 DPI" -- Well.. we've made it up to 320 DPI now, only 5 years later. Hasn't quite become affordable for full-size monitors and TVs, but a few more years and we'll be there I think!